# Highcharts: drawDataLabels wrapper function for pie chart not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I have written a wrapper function for drawing data labels of a pie chart. In the wrapper function, I have updated distance attribute of data labels. But when I give size attribute in user options, distance does not work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/8L5dxa6c/1/

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function(drawDataLabels) {
      this.chart.series[0].options.dataLabels.distance = -30;
      drawDataLabels.apply(this);
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

The distance has to be updated in wrapper function as it required in my scenario. What can be the reason for drawDataLabels to fail when size is specified in JSON options?

Comment: Hi, I am wondering what is the main goal behind this wrapper? Because you are able to add distance inside your userOptions without any problems.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I need to set distance according to pie size which is not known at the time of creating options

Comment: I think that you can add userOptions.dataLabels object as well, here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/u1q0j8eL/1/

Comment: But you have called update() api here.. Is there any way without using that?

Comment: I think that you need to use series.update(). I think that you can even change this distance property in your load event callback function(with series.update), instead of wrapping your code.